# Javascript pass array of arguments using `apply()`, but keep `this` reference from `call()`

Tags: javascript, call, apply

I need to combine the power of JavaScript's `call()` and `apply()` methods.  The problem I am having is that `call()` retains the proper reference to `this`, but sends the argument array that I have as an array when I need it sent as function arguments. The `apply()` method sends the arguments to the function just fine when using an array, but I don't know how to send it the proper reference to `this` that the `call()` method seems to naturally have access to.

Below is a simplified version of the code that I have, it probably looks pretty useless, but its a good way to get the point across:

```
// AN OBJECT THAT HOLDS SOME FUNCTIONS
var main = {};
main.the_number = 15;
main.some_function = function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    // WOULD VERY MUCH LIKE THIS TO PRINT '15' TO THE SCREEN
    alert(this.the_number);
    // DO SOME STUFF WITH THE ARGUMENTS
    ... 
};
// THIS STORES FUNCTIONS FOR LATER.
//  'hub' has no direct knowledge of 'main'
var hub = {};
hub.methods = [];
hub.methods.push(main.some_function);
hub.do_methods = function(arguments_array){
    for(var i=0; i<this.methods.length; i++){
        // With this one, '15' is printed just fine, but an array holding 'i' is 
        //  just passed instead if 'i' itself
        this.methods[i].call(arguments_array);   
        // With this one, 'i' is passed as a function argument, but now the
        //  'this' reference to main is lost when calling the function 
        this.methods[i].apply(--need a reference to 'main' here--, arguments_array); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The first argument of apply sets `this` to whatever you pass it... if you want `this == main` then just pass `main` as the first argument.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus - Unfortunately, 'hub' has no direct knowledge of 'main'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What? [Apply passes the scope as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)...

```
method.apply(this, [args]);
```

**Edit:**

In your code you have the main object defined in the containing scope so you can simply do;

```
this.methods[i].call(main);
```

or

```
this.methods[i].apply(main, [args]);
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but in the context of this code, I don't see how to get to the 'this' that I need to pass to "apply".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if I do the code in your answer, it will pass a reference to 'hub' and not 'main'

Comment: Unfortunately, 'hub' has no direct knowledge of 'main'

Comment: I was afraid of that. Are you sure though? I thought maybe it could be since the information is obviously there, since "call()" actually has access to it?

Comment: Call does not have access to it. The Object being used as `this` is whatever you pass to it. In your case it was an array.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That makes perfect sense then. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! All you need to do is save `main` in `hub`. Then you can pass it back to the function.

Comment: It *can* be done if `some_function` holds a reference to `main` as a member function, e.g., `some_function.main_ref = main`.  You smuggle the reference to `main` into `hub` inside the function object.

Answer (score 2):

When using `apply` and `call` the 1st parameter is what you want `this` to be set to.

`call` takes a list of arguments:

```
.call(main, i, j)
```

and `apply` takes an array or arguments:

```
.apply(main, [i, j])
```

So, on this line:

```
this.methods[i].call([i]);
```

This passes `[i]` as `this` inside `this.methods[i]`.

You probably want to do:

```
this.methods[i].call(main, i);
```

This will call `this.methods[i]`, set `this` to `main`, and pass `i` to it.

Or:

```
this.methods[i].call(main, arguments_array);
```

This will call `this.methods[i]`, set `this` to `main`, and pass the elements of `arguments_array` as parameters.

Comment: In the context of the code above, how do I get at 'main' so I can pass it to apply? (Assuming that 'hub' has not direct knowledge of 'main'?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow: `hub` needs to have "direct knowledge" of `main`.  There's no way for it to "figure out" that you want to use `main`.

Comment: I apologize that my example was a little weak. I cannot change the way the arguments are passed, they must be passed as an array and interpreted by the function as normal argument parameters. I changed the example accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow: Then you want to use `.apply` instead of `.call`.  Either way, `hub` needs to know about `main` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just attach a reference to the parent object to the function object:

```
main.some_function = function () {
    //...
}
main.some_function.parent = main;

// now some_function.parent holds a ref to main
```

Or, if you like, closures to the rescue: include a reference to `main` when you define `main.some_function`:

```
// self-execution function the returns a function with `that` (i.e., main) in scope
main.some_function = (function(that) {
    return function() {
        alert(that.the_number);
    }
})(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I read the comments in the preceding answers, I think, that you need some kind of binding. You can either use jQuery or similar library, or implement it yourself:

```
var bound_some_function = function(){
    return main.some_function.apply(main, arguments);
}
// ...
hub.methods.push(bound_some_function);
// ...
this.methods[i].apply(null /*whathever, has no effect*/, arguments_array);
```

Universal definition of a bind function looks like this:

```
function bind(fun, scope){
    return function(){
        return fun.apply(scope, arguments);
    };
}
```

For further reading about binding, google "Javascript function binding". There are lots of articles about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrect information before (in my deleted answer), since the apply will not have effects in a binded function (as the answer above);

Just adding a easy code to prove:

```
/*Lets suppose we have a class "MessageReader" that has a method printMessage
 * that for some reason needs to receive the message to be printed from a function,
 * not directly a value.*/
function MessageReader() {
    this.value = "This is NOT a message and is not supposed to be readed!";
}
/*getMessage needs to return a string that will be printed!*/
MessageReader.prototype.printMessage = function(getMessage) {
    console.log(getMessage.apply(this, []));
}

function Message(value) {
    this.value = value;
}
Message.prototype.getMessage = function() {
    return this.value;
}


var myMessageReader = new MessageReader();
var myMessage1 = new Message("This is a simple message");
var myMessage2 = new Message("This is another simple message");

/*This will print the wrong message:*/
myMessageReader.printMessage(myMessage1.getMessage);

/*But this works!*/
myMessageReader.printMessage(myMessage2.getMessage.bind(myMessage2));
```

Comment: If your previous answer was an answer, then you should have edited it with updated information instead of deleting it. In this new answer, your references to a deleted answer will help nobody, because they cannot see it... it's _deleted_, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `.call()` and `.apply()` methods do not differ in terms of their handling with `this`. From the MDN documentation:

> While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of apply(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Unfortunately, calling a function with call / bind / apply and maintaining it's original `this` reference isn't possible, however, as ugly is this may seem, there is a workaround where you can pass

```
function applyOriginalThis(fn, parametersArray)
{
    var p = parametersArray;

    switch (p.length)
    {
        case 0: fn(); break;
        case 1: fn(p[0]); break;
        case 2: fn(p[0], p[1]); break;
        case 3: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2]); break;
        case 4: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]); break;
        case 5: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]); break;
        case 6: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]); break;
        case 7: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6]); break;
        case 8: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7]); break;
        case 9: fn(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6], p[7], p[8]); break;
        default: throw "Too many parameters.";
    }
}
```

Of course, this will only work for the number of parameters that you wish to support. On the bright side, functions that take an excessive number of parameters is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Also, if I'm not mistaken, this type of code pattern was used in AngularJS 1.x as a performance optimization on `.apply()` (can't find a reference right now).